Symbols in files are being automatically replaced with replacement symbols
I am trying to write hexadecimal to a file in Python, and hex values above 127 are being replaced with replacement symbols with the hex value EF BF BD when I try to read or download the file.
Here is the code I am using to write to the file:
open('test.bin', 'wb').write(bytes([188]))

Here is the code I am using to read the file:
print(open('test.bin', 'rb').read())

After writing to the file with the above code, I replaced the code with the code to read the file listed above. In the console b'\xff' was printed as expected. Once I open the file the characters are replaced with replacement characters. This behavior occurs if I download the file, use the hex editor extension in Replit, and copy and paste the text within the file to an online hex editor. It almost appears that once the code is done executing Replit does formatting. What is interesting is if I read the file again with the code, the same value,b'\xff', is printed. What can I do to prevent the symbols from being replaced with replacement characters, especially when downloading the file?
The expected behavior is for the symbols to remain the same as when the code wrote them. The value being written, 188 in the code given, is just a placeholder for whichever particular value I need to write. I am using the 8xv format, an obscure format used for Ti-84 Calculator files.
Any help would be appreciated!
